# Filter Google Map Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have passed different information into my custom Google Map as below;

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon:image,
    title: locations[i][0],
    price: locations[i][3],
    occupancy: locations[i][4],
});
```

I am trying to filter the markers when a button is clicked;

```
$(document).on('click', '#price-filter', function(){
    $.each(map.markers, function(i, marker) {
        if(marker.price <= '80.00')
            marker.visible = false;
        else
            marker.visible = true;
    });
});
```

This is not running, I have tried the on click within the `function initMap() {}` and outside of it but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

*EDIT* Please find the JSFiddle located https://jsfiddle.net/g19avj3e/

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: sorry have created a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g19avj3e/

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in the question itself**, not on external site.  Your fiddle doesn't work: `Uncaught InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function`

Comment: There is no `map.markers` array.  [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/g19avj3e/2/) (shows map).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move the on click function inside the `initMap` function (so the DOM is rendered and it can find the #price-filter check box), it runs.  But there is no `map.markers` array.  You can create that array and push your markers onto it:

```
// before loop
map.markers = [];

// inside loop
map.markers.push(marker);
```

The next issue is that there is no documented `.visible` property of a marker, you need to use the documented `.setVisible()` method.

```
$(document).on('click', '#price-filter', function(){
    $.each(map.markers, function(i, marker) {
        if(marker.price <= '80.00')
            marker.setVisible(false);
        else
            marker.setVisible(true);
    });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/g19avj3e/3/)